# closing exe process after tkinter app is closed

Tags: tkinter, py2exe

**SITUATION**

I have built an executable file for a Tkinter app and i tried running the exe file.

When i run the exe file and immediately close it after opening (using the exit button) the process is shown to be killed in the task manager.

But when i run the exe and making it do a process and then closing it after, the process lingers in the task manager. Creating duplicate processes when i try to run the exe again.

**QUESTION**

How do i kill the process of the exe when closing the Tkinter app?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? The process that you are running,is it an external script that you called?

Comment: Nope it is not an external script. It's more like an app that would wait for a user input and execute an arithmetic process after pressing a button.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking into this problem for so long as well. Finally, I found the answer:

```
def destroyer():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destroyer)
```

Comment: Good answer, also, if you have more than one window use a second line for when the exit button is pressed on the other Tkinter Window.


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destroyer)
Other_Tkinter_Window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destroyer)

Answer (score 0):

i figured out that the program itself does not even end in the python shell that is why I implemented

```
def destroyer():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",destroyer)
```

and after building it to exe, the process already terminates when i close the Tkinter GUI app.